# How many numbers are with $5$ different digits in decreasing order?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I mean that $54321$ is a valid number, but $16755$ is not.

I was thinking that there are $6^5$ possible numbers because there are 6 possibilities for each position in the number, but I don't know exaclty.

Comment: Why are there $6$ possibilities for each position?

Comment: Do leading zeroes count ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Leading zeroes don't matter since no decreasing sequence can begin with a zero.

Comment: @chaos: ooops, quite right ! Thanks.

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean *strictly decreasing* or  *non-increasing* like *66531*

Comment: @trueblueanil the digits should be *different* (per the question title), so I would presume they mean *strictly decreasing*

Comment: @hgmath: Yea, overlooked that ! (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each number between $0$ and $9$ can appear exactly once or not at all (since there can be no repetitions). Given a set of five such numbers (say $\{1, 3, 0, 5, 8\}$) there is exactly one corresponding decreasing sequence (85310). So the number of decreasing sequences is the number of ways to choose 5 elements from a set of 10 digits. This is just
$$ {10 \choose 5} = 252 \,. $$

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for that, I missed the word in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively: these numbers correspond one-to-one to $5$-element subsets of $\{0,\dots,9\}$ (the set of the digits), so their number is $\binom{10}{5}=252$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5$ distinct numbers made of $6$ digits. Divide this amount by $5!$ to only allow the decreasing permutations.